# Verifying that a string starts with a number (easy) OR exactly 3 letters?

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to make a RegEx expression to verify that a field starts with either the number 3 - the easy part - or starts with three letters, then continues to be numbers

My expression so far is

^((3)[\d])|([a-zA-Z]{3}[\d])$

The expression stops you from doing anything BELOW 3, but it still lets you go over...

I've done some searching and can't find a topic that relates to the issue of having an exact amount of characters

And I'm having trouble with limiting it to exactly 3 letter characters. Unfortunately what I'm working with, it HAS to be RegEx and not another language.

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Also when it starts with exactly three letters. What is allowed after that? Just digits? spaces?

Comment: Can you add please examples of the strings that pass and that do not pass?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure, I'm building the expression on a web platform so I am asking them now

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Just digits after the 3 letters

Comment: @MargaritaLitkevych An example of a pass would be ABC123456 or just 123123456

Comment: How can `123123456` pass if it does not start with `3` and there are no 3 letters at the beginning?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mistype, was meant to type '321'123... sorry :P

Comment: just a quick shot https://regex101.com/r/tD2nK4/1

Comment: Also, to just check, you do not need to match the whole string. [`^(?:3|[a-zA-Z]{3})`](https://regex101.com/r/qX2tC3/1) seems enough.

Comment: @SebastianProske in the platform i'm using, that allows the use of just 3 letters without any digits following, which i'm not going for

Comment: @LukeSheldon adjusted this in my answer. You might edit your sample strings into the question, so one doesn't have to look through the comments for them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?:3|[a-zA-Z]{3})\d+$
```

verifies, that your string starts with either 3 or 3 letters and then is only followed by numbers (at least one) until the end of the string

See https://regex101.com/r/tD2nK4/3 for some positive and negative examples

Comment: That seems to work! Could you explain what the colon is doing as if I was an idiot?

Comment: `(?:` is starting a non capturing group, it's basically the same as just `(` but doesn't enclose anything into a group

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do exactly what you want:

```
^((3)[\d])|([a-zA-Z]{3}[^a-zA-Z])
```

Please note that this regex can only cope with the ASCII alphabet.